# Web service REST con GX17/.Net

Tags: .net, webservice, rest, genexus

Traté de generar un web service REST con Genexus 17 generando .Net y cuando lo consumo desde SoapUI o Postman me devuelve Error 404. También quise consumirlo desde un web panel hecho con genexus y me da error IHttpHandler Exception desde el servidor donde está instalado.

El procedimiento tiene la siguiente configuración en las propiedades:

```
Expose as web server: TRUE
REST Protocol:        TRUE
Generate OpenAPI interface:TRUE
```

Traté de consumirlo así:
http://myHostNameOrIPAddress/MyVirtualDir/ws_procName?parm=value
ó
http://myHostNameOrIPAddress/MyVirtualDir/ws_procName.aspx?parm=value
no sé bien si tengo que poner el ".aspx" porque el procedimiento, como dice en la GXWiki, no es main.

También traté de ver si el ws está activo usando la siguiente URL:http://myHostNameOrIPAddress/MyVirtualDir/ws_procName.aspx?wadl

Luego probé de consumirlo con un web panel hecho en gx con httpclient así, este es el código del el evento asociado a un botón en pantalla luego que se
ingresa el parámetro de entrada:

```
&HttpClient.Host = "myHostNameOrIPAddress" 
&HttpClient.BaseUrl= "/MyVirtualDir/" 
&HttpClient.Port = 80 
&HttpClient.Secure = 0 
&HttpClient.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
&JsonSend = &ws_sdtInput.ToJson()   //&ws_sdtInput es el sdt para el parametro de entrada después de importar la OpenAPI 

&HttpClient.AddString(&JsonSend.Trim()) 
&HttpClient.Execute("POST", "/messages/ws_procName.json") 
&JsonResponse = &ws_sdtOutput.ToJson() //&ws_sdtOutput es el sdt para el parametro de salida después de importar la OpenAPI 

&JsonResponse = &HttpClient.ToString()
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como consumir web services REST con genexus? Gracias.

Comment: Agrega tu codigo, para saber de que estamos hablando,

Comment: Estoy usando Gx 17 generando .Net con IIS7.  Traté de consumirlo así: http://myHostNameOrIPAddress/MyVirtualDir/ws_procName?parm=value ó http://myHostNameOrIPAddress/MyVirtualDir/ws_procName.aspx?parm=value no sé bien si tengo que poner el ".aspx" porque el procedimiento, como dice en la GXWiki, no es main. También traté de ver si el ws está activo usando la siguiente URL:http://myHostNameOrIPAddress/MyVirtualDir/ws_procName.aspx?wadl

Comment: Después de no poder con lo anterior, traté de consumirlo con un web panel de gx con httpclient así: 
&HttpClient.Host = "http://myHostNameOrIPAddress" 
&HttpClient.BaseUrl= "/MyVirtualDir/"
&HttpClient.Port = 80 &HttpClient.Secure = 0 
&HttpClient.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")

Comment: &JsonSend = &ws_sdtInput.ToJson() //&ws_sdtInput es el sdt para el parametro de entrada después de importar la OpenAPI &HttpClient.AddString(&JsonSend.Trim()) 
&HttpClient.Execute("POST", "/messages/ws_procName.json") 
&JsonResponse = &ws_sdtOutput.ToJson()  //&ws_sdtOutput es el sdt para el parametro de salida después de importar la OpenAPI 
&JsonResponse = &HttpClient.ToString()

Comment: Supon que tu llegas a esta pregunta, te daras cuenta que no se entiende, edita tu pregunta y agrega el codigo asi como comentarios en la parte que no entiendes, saludos

Comment: Edité la pregunta y le puse mis comentarios y código en ella, espero sea más entendible...no conocía la sintaxis para mostrar código. Disculpas!

Answer (score 0):

Ese error puede significar:

- Que el módulo URL Rewrite no está instalado, puedes ver cómo
  instalarlo en:
  https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?14958,How+to+install+URL+Rewrite
- Que los archivos .svc no se implementaron correctamente. Probar con [Rest tester tool](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18365,REST%20Web%20Services%20Installation%20Troubleshootinghttps://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18365,REST%20Web%20Services%20Installation%20Troubleshootinghttps://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18365,REST%20Web%20Services%20Installation%20Troubleshooting).
- Que está pendiente una configuración del IIS. Se necesitan registrar
  las extensiones SVC mediante el comando:

```
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" –i
```

Comment: OK, gracias por tu respuesta!!!

Answer (score 0):

Fijate en el objeto API como esta configurada la base url, generalemente es /api/nombre_api. Ese valor es el que tenes que colocar en &HttpClient.BaseUrl. Posiblemente por eso es que te tira el error 404

Comment: Pero no dijo que es un objeto api, es un procedure expuesto como rest.. está escribiendo mal la url

Answer (score 0):

Estás escribiendo mal la url para consumirlo.

La url no lleva el ".aspx". Lo llevaría si fuese un procedure main con call protocol=http.

Cuando intentas verlo con ?/wsdl, eso es para servicios de tipo soap, es completamente otra cosa distinta a servicios rest.

Siendo un procedure expuesto como servicio rest debes llamarlo colocando la baseurl/rest/procedure
Los parámetros irán en la url o en el body del http, según que tipo de servicio y método sea.
Error 404 es claramente no existe, pero porque la llamada es incorrecta.

No confundirse con el objetivo api, que si bien es similar en las llamadas, no es lo que mencionas estar haciendo.

Intuyo que estás en tus primeras experiencias con webservices y puede que por momentos sientas que es todo una gran confusión,  pero es mucho más simple de lo que parece.

En tus comentarios mencionas que consultaste en la wiki, no se cuál será la que estás viendo, pero la que menciona lo relacionado a tu pregunta es esta:

[https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?15314,HowTo%3A+Consume+a+Procedure+exposed+as+a+Rest+service](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?15314,HowTo%3A%20Consume%20a%20Procedure%20exposed%20as%20a%20Rest%20service)